# Place image before text

Tags: css

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="md-checkbox" style="color: white;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="private" class="md-check" id="checkbox2">
    <label for="checkbox2">
    <span class="inc"></span>
    <span class="check"></span>
    <span class="box"></span>
    List this item privately for $3.00 </label>
</div>
```

I wish to place an small image(icon)before the '$3.00' text. I've tried creating a custom class and using a span however this didn't work. Could someone please point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Why are you asking about SASS / SCSS?

Comment: Because I'll likely have to do some CSS changes for this, this makes people aware that I'm using SCSS.

Comment: SCSS is a precompiled language that compiles to CSS. The details of SCSS are not relevant for the purpose of generating the appropriate selectors or HTML structure.

Comment: Now that you've changed your question, you did 2 things: You rendered the answers you got useless - since the solution no longer match the requirements, and you've made your question worthless - since it's impossible to do (without changing the HTML) and doesn't even make much sense. Please **DON'T DO THAT**.

Comment: Hmm, sorry... let me just leave my incorrect description in there...

Answer (score 0):

Considering your markup, you'll need to tweak it a bit. Would something like this work or are you completely unable to adjust your markup?

**HTML (2nd to last line)**

```
List this item privately for <i class="icon"></i>$3.00 </label>
```

**CSS**

```
.icon:after {
    content: url('image.png');
}
```

Comment: Apologies, type in the description. Updated now

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect new question.

Comment: This gives the following result: https://gyazo.com/8eeac9f58fc93696f1c0d638f15191df

Comment: Looks like the image is in front of the $3.00 like your question asked for?  If you want to position the image, add additional CSS props like `transform: translate()` and `vertical-align` to get it where you want it.  You can also specify width and height and other things to make it look like you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:last-of-type` pseudo-class selector, along with the `::after` pseudo-element selector to add content after the last `<span>` within the `.md-checkbox` classed element (your div...). The content basically be anything you need:

```css
.md-checkbox span:last-of-type::after {
  content: "*"
}
```

```html
<div class="md-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="private" class="md-check" id="checkbox2">
    <label for="checkbox2">
    <span class="inc"></span>
    <span class="check"></span>
    <span class="box"></span>
    List this item privately for $3.00 </label>
</div>
```